# How to Activate feature across all sub-sites in a web Application programatically -SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

How to activate feature using C# code programmatic ally for multiple sub-sites . my feature is deployed "site" level .

Is there anyway we can automatically activate the feature to all the sub-sites?

Comment: You can only activate Site level features to site collection only. You can't activate it to sub site.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint features can exist at several different scopes, including Web, Site, and Web Application.  Each of these can be activated and deactivated programmatically, but they have to be handled slightly differently.

For Site:

```
{SPSite}.Features.Add(FeatureGuid);

{SPSite}.Features.Remove(FeatureGuid, true);
```

For Web :

```
{SPWeb}.Features.Add(FeatureGuid);

{SPWeb}.Features.Remove(FeatureGuid, true);
```

Example :

```
Guid featureGuid = new Guid(”[Feature-GUID-Here]″);
if (web.Features[featureGuid] == null) 
{
         web.Features.Add(featureGuid);
}
```

To activate features on the Farm level , it's a little bit tricky :

```
SPWebApplication webApplication= web.Site.WebApplication;
if(webApplication.WebService.Features[featureGuid]==null)
{
       webApplication.WebService.Features.Add(featureGuid);
}
```

Loop through all sub sites and activate feature

```
 SPSite osite = properties.Feature.Parent as SPSite;
    foreach(SPWeb oWeb in site.AllWebs) 
    {
        if (oWeb .Features[featureGuid] == null) 
        { 
            oWeb .Features.Add(featureGuid);
        } 
    }
```

Comment: HI can send me the full code . i am getting erros

Comment: What error did you got? Please share it

Comment: SPSite osite = properties.Feature.Parent as SPSite;
            SPWeb web = osite.OpenWeb();
            foreach (SPWeb webApplication in osite.AllWebs)
            {
                SPSite site = webApplication.Site;

                if (site.Features[featureGuid] == null)
                {
                    site.Features.Add(featureGuid);
                }

            }

Comment: For each loop i am getting the error ones you check and tell me the correct code i am deploy the "site" scoped feature.

Comment: If you are using site scoped feature.. The below code is enough  SPSite osite = properties.Feature.Parent as SPSite; 
if (osite.Features[featureGuid] == null) { osite.Features.Add(featureGuid); } }

Comment: thanks  . if we deploy "site" scoped feature is possible activate all sub sites?

Comment: Ur Welcome. I think so. Mark this as answer :)

Comment: How to activate Feature  all sub sites in "site" scoped feature. Give me any Code

Comment: Edited the answer :)